# DOJO: onClick not always called in custom widget

Tags: events, dojo, onclick, widget

I've run into a problem with Dojo 1.10 and need some suggestions on how to figure out the culprit.  I have a custom widget, TaskButton, that implements the onMouseDown, onMouseUp, and onClick methods.  All three have logging statements.  The onMouseDown and onMouseUp always gets called and the correct times and their log statements show up in the console.  But, onClick sometimes is never called despite repeatedly clicking in the TaskButton.  Most of the time clicking outside the TaskButton then back inside it makes the onClick work but not always.  When the onClick does not get called its log statement does not show up in the console.

TaskButton.js custom widget

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/event",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom-class",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/mouse",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/topic",
    "dijit/Menu",
    "dijit/MenuItem",
    "dijit/MenuSeparator",
    "dijit/PopupMenuItem",
    "dijit/popup",
    "dijit/Tooltip",
    "dijit/Tree",
    "dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/TaskButton.html"
], function(declare, event, lang, domClass, domConstruct, mouse, on, query, topic, Menu, MenuItem, MenuSeparator, PopupMenuItem,
        Popup, Tooltip, Tree, ForestStoreModel, registry, button, _WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template){
    return declare("TaskButton", [_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Menu], {
      scene:0,
      sceneId:0,
      target:"",
      state:"pending",
      cloudCover: false,
      cloudPercentage: 0,
      targetInterest: false,
      hsv: false,
      previousState:"pending",
      backgroundcolor:"#414141",
      templateString:template,
      baseClass: "TaskButton",
      innerNode:undefined,
      cm:null,
      theTask:null,
      eventHandle:null,

postCreate: function()
{
    // Get a DOM node reference for the root of our widget
    var domNode = this.domNode;
    this.innerNode = domNode.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;

    domClass.replace(this.innerFill, "task"+this.state+"Background", "task"+this.state+"Background");
    if (this.cloudCover && ((this.state === "Ready") || (this.state === "Unassigned"))) {
        domClass.replace(this.innerFill, "task"+"Red"+"Background", "task"+this.state+"Background");
    }
    this.previousState = this.state;
    console.log("getting context menu for Scene-" + this.scene + "ContextMenu");
    cm = registry.byId("Scene-" + this.scene + "ContextMenu");

    this.own(
      on(domNode, "contextmenu", lang.hitch(this, "_showContextMenu"))
    );

    this.inherited(arguments);
},

startup: function()
{
   //Turn off button icons if warranted Must do here after dom nodes built
   if (!this.cloudCover)
   {
     dojo.style(dojo.byId("Scene-"+this.scene+"Cloud"), "display", "none");
   }
   if (!this.targetInterest)
   {
     dojo.style(dojo.byId("Scene-"+this.scene+"Target"), "display", "none");
   }
   if (!this.hsv)
   {
     dojo.style(dojo.byId("Scene-"+this.scene+"HSV"), "display", "none");
   }

   this.inherited(arguments);
},

test: function(sceneId)
{
  console.log("testing");
              if (sceneId != this.scene)
              {
                  domClass.replace("Scene-" + sceneId + "Fill", "taskInnerFill", "taskInnerFillSelected");
              }
},

buildRendering: function()
{
  console.log("buildRendering scene:" + this.scene);
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
uninitialize: function()
{
  if (this.eventHandle != null)
  {
    console.log("unsubscribing from event topic");
    eventHandle.remove();
    eventHandle = null;
  }
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
_onMenuClick: function(event)
{
  console.log("menu item clicked");
},

_showContextMenu: function(event) {
  console.log("opening context menu for scene:" + this.scene);

  this.inherited(arguments);
},

// This is always called
_onMouseDown: function(e)
{
    var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes["scene"].value;
    if (e.button == 0)
    {
      console.log("mouse left pressed, scene=" + scene + " button=" + e.button);
      domClass.replace("Scene-" + scene + "OuterBorder", "taskOuterBorderPressed", "taskOuterBorder");
    }
    else if (e.button == 2)
    {
      console.log("mouse right pressed, scene=" + scene + " button=" + e.button);
      domClass.replace("Scene-" + scene + "OuterBorder", "taskOuterBorderPressed", "taskOuterBorder");
    }

    this.inherited(arguments);
},

// This is always called
_onMouseUp: function(e)
{
    var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes["scene"].value;
    if (e.button == 0)
    {
      console.log("mouse left released, scene=" + scene + " button=" + e.button);
    }
    else if (e.button == 2)
    {
      console.log("mouse right released, scene=" + scene + " button=" + e.button);
    }
  domClass.replace("Scene-" + this.scene + "OuterBorder", "taskOuterBorder", "taskOuterBorderPressed");
  dijit.hideTooltip(e.currentTarget);
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
_onMouseEnter: function(e)
{
    label = "Scene: " + this.scene + "<BR>State: " + this.state + "<BR>Target: " + this.target;
    dijit.showTooltip(label,e.currentTarget);
    dijit.popup.close();
    this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
_onMouseLeave: function(e)
{
  this._onMouseUp("");
  this.inherited(arguments);
  dijit.hideTooltip(e.currentTarget);
},

// This is what is not always called
_onClick: function(e)
{
  var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes["scene"].value;
  console.log("scene " + scene + " clicked");
  this._publishEvent(this.scene, "clicked");
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
_onBlur: function(e)
{
  dijit.popup.close();
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

//
_onContextMenu: function(e)
{
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this._publishEvent({"scene":this.scene,"sceneId":this.sceneId}, "clicked");
    dijit.hideTooltip(e.currentTarget);
    var widget = this;
    theNode = "TaskButtonContainer" + widget.scene;
    console.log("mouse right clicked, scene=" + widget.scene + " target: " + e.target + "current target");

                theTask = missionCache.query({"sceneId" : this.scene}).then( function(results) {
                theTask = results;
                if (widget.state === "Unassigned" || widget.state === "Ready") {
                    //The context menu should fire to allow assignment

                    var cb = new dijit.form.ComboBox({style:"width:96%;background-color:#414141;margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:4px;",
                        name:"usersByTask", placeholder:"Assign this task to: ", store:usersContextMenuCB,

                        labelAttr: 'name',
                        searchAttr: 'name',

                        onChange: function(){
                            theTask[0].taskStatus = "Assigned";
                            theTask[0].taskOwner = this.item.userName;
                            missionCache.put(theTask[0]);
                            console.log("nothing");
                            widget.set("state", "Assigned");
                            assignTask(this.item.userName);
                            widget.domNode.classList.remove("Unassigned");
                            widget.domNode.classList.add("Assigned");
                            widget.domNode.setAttribute("dndtype", "Assigned");
                            this.destroy();

                        },
                        onClose: function() { this.destroy();}
                    });
                    cb.toggleDropDown();
                    dijit.popup.open({parent: widget, popup:cb, around:e.target,
                        onClose: function(){
                            dijit.popup.close(cb);
                        }
                    });
                }
                });
},


_publishEvent: function(sceneNumber, eventName)
{
  console.log("publishing " + eventName + " for scene " + sceneNumber);
  topic.publish("TaskButton/tasks", { scene:sceneNumber, task:this, event:eventName });
},

_setStateAttr: function(newState)
{
    if (newState != "")
    {
        console.log("setting state for scene:" + this.scene + " to " + newState);
        this._set("state", newState);
        if (this.innerNode !== undefined)
        {
        domClass.replace(this.innerFill, "task"+newState+"Background", "task"+this.previousState+"Background");
        }
        this.previousState = this.state;
        this.state = newState;
    }
  this.inherited(arguments);
},

_changeTaskState: function(newState)
  {
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
      var node = registry.byId(clickedItem);
      if (node !== undefined)
      {
        node.set("state", newState);
        console.log("changed task " + this.clickedItem + " state to " + newState);
      }
    });
  this.inherited(arguments);
  },

  _menuTaskDetails: function(e)
  {
    console.log("do task deatils");
  }

});
})
```

There are attach events for all the button actions in the template.

TaskButton.html template:

```
    <li class="dojoDndItem" dndType="${state}" style="border:none;padding:0" data-dojo-props="scene:${scene}">
<div id="TaskButtonContainer-${scene}" widgetid="TaskButtonContainer-${scene}" class="${baseClass}" data-dojo-attach-point="taskButtonContainer"
     data-dojo-attach-event="onContextMenu:_showContextMenu">
   <div widgetid="Scene-${scene}ContextMenu" data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu" data-dojo-props="contextMenuForWindow:false"
       data-dojo-attach-point="contextMenu" targetNodeIds="Scene-${scene}Fill" style="display: none;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:_menuTaskDetails">
      Task Details
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Scene-${scene}OuterBorder" widgetid="Scene-${scene}OuterBorder" class="taskOuterBorder" data-dojo-attach-point="outerBorder" scene="${scene}">
    <div id="Scene-${scene}Fill" class="taskInnerFill task${state}Background" data-dojo-attach-point="innerFill" scene="${scene}"
       data-dojo-attach-event="onMouseDown:_onMouseDown,onMouseUp:_onMouseUp,onDijitClick:_onClick,onMouseEnter:_onMouseEnter,onMouseLeave:_onMouseLeave,onContextMenu:_onContextMenu,onBlur:_onBlur">
      <div id="Scene-${scene}Text" class="taskText" data-dojo-attach-point="text">
            <table style="margin:0;padding:0">
              <tr>
                <td>${scene}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img id="Scene-${scene}Cloud" src="img/cloud.png" alt="Cloud cover" height="21" width="21">
                  <img id="Scene-${scene}Target" src="img/target.png" alt="ATR" height="21" width="21">
                  <img id="Scene-${scene}HSV" src="img/HSV.png" alt="HSV" height="21" width="21">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

I've also cleaned up the code per the suggestions and there is no change in the behavior of the TaskButton's onClick event handler.

Comment: can you share the TaskButton code ? it is very hard to guess what is wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,
There is multiple errors...

- you don't need to inherits from `_WidgetBase`, `_TemplatedMixin` and `_OnDijitClickMixin`, they come with `Menu`
- `Menu` should be the Base (so should be first in the inheritance list)
- you should no use `domNode.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild` but instead you should use a `data-dojo-attach-point` in the template
- `cm = registry.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'ContextMenu');` should be `this.cm = registry.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'ContextMenu');`
- `dojo` namespace should not be used. So `dojo.style` should be replaced by a require to `dojo/dom-style` and `domStyle.set()` and `dojo.byId` should be replaced by a require to `dojo/dom` and `dom.byId()`
- `dijit` namespace should not be used. So `dijit.hideTooltip` should be replaced by a require to `dijit/Tooltip` then `Tooltip.hide()` and `dijit.showTooltip` should be replaced by `Tooltip.show()` and `dijit.popup.close()` should be replaced by a require to `dijit/_base/popup` then `popup.close()` and `dijit.popup.open()` should be replaced by `popup.open()`
- `var` is missing before `label` in method `_onMouseEnter`
- in `onChange` of the `dijit.form.ComboBox` you call a non existing method `assignTask`
- in `_changeTaskState` method you require `dijit/registry` but it is already available. So the extra require is useless
- probably many more but I am not there to refactor your code
- finally nothing is attached to your `_onClick` method. I don't event understand how it can be sometimes executed... Butmaybe it is connected using `data-dojo-attach-event` ? If yes, then please also provide your template.

Try to apply all the changes to cleanup some mistakes, and see if it works better.
If no, please share the template of your button.

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dojo/_base/event',
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-class',
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/dom-style',
    'dojo/mouse',
    'dojo/on',
    'dojo/query',
    'dojo/topic',
    'dijit/Menu',
    'dijit/MenuItem',
    'dijit/MenuSeparator',
    'dijit/PopupMenuItem',
    'dijit/popup',
    'dijit/Tooltip',
    'dijit/Tree',
    'dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel',
    'dijit/registry',
    'dijit/_base/popup',
    'dijit/form/Button',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
    'dojo/text!./templates/TaskButton.html'
], function(declare, event, lang, dom, domClass, domConstruct, domStyle, mouse, on, query, topic, Menu, MenuItem, MenuSeparator, PopupMenuItem,
    Popup, Tooltip, Tree, ForestStoreModel, registry, popup, button, _WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {
    return declare('TaskButton', [Menu, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        scene: 0,
        sceneId: 0,
        target: '',
        state: 'pending',
        cloudCover: false,
        cloudPercentage: 0,
        targetInterest: false,
        hsv: false,
        previousState: 'pending',
        backgroundcolor: '#414141',
        templateString: template,
        baseClass: 'TaskButton',
        innerNode: undefined,
        cm: null,
        theTask: null,
        eventHandle: null,

        postCreate: function() {
            // Get a DOM node reference for the root of our widget
            var domNode = this.domNode;
            this.innerNode = domNode.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;

            domClass.replace(this.innerFill, 'task' + this.state + 'Background', 'task' + this.state + 'Background');
            if (this.cloudCover && ((this.state === 'Ready') || (this.state === 'Unassigned'))) {
                domClass.replace(this.innerFill, 'task' + 'Red' + 'Background', 'task' + this.state + 'Background');
            }
            this.previousState = this.state;
            console.log('getting context menu for Scene-' + this.scene + 'ContextMenu');
            cm = registry.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'ContextMenu');

            this.own(
                on(domNode, 'contextmenu', lang.hitch(this, '_showContextMenu'))
            );

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        startup: function() {
            //Turn off button icons if warranted Must do here after dom nodes built
            if (!this.cloudCover) {
                domStyle.set(dom.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'Cloud'), 'display', 'none');
            }
            if (!this.targetInterest) {
                domStyle.set(dom.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'Target'), 'display', 'none');
            }
            if (!this.hsv) {
                domStyle.set(dom.byId('Scene-' + this.scene + 'HSV'), 'display', 'none');
            }

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        test: function(sceneId) {
            console.log('testing');
            if (sceneId != this.scene) {
                domClass.replace('Scene-' + sceneId + 'Fill', 'taskInnerFill', 'taskInnerFillSelected');
            }
        },

        buildRendering: function() {
            console.log('buildRendering scene:' + this.scene);
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        uninitialize: function() {
            if (this.eventHandle != null) {
                console.log('unsubscribing from event topic');
                eventHandle.remove();
                eventHandle = null;
            }
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        _onMenuClick: function(event) {
            console.log('menu item clicked');
        },

        _showContextMenu: function(event) {
            console.log('opening context menu for scene:' + this.scene);

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        // This is always called
        _onMouseDown: function(e) {
            var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes['scene'].value;
            if (e.button == 0) {
                console.log('mouse left pressed, scene=' + scene + ' button=' + e.button);
                domClass.replace('Scene-' + scene + 'OuterBorder', 'taskOuterBorderPressed', 'taskOuterBorder');
            } else if (e.button == 2) {
                console.log('mouse right pressed, scene=' + scene + ' button=' + e.button);
                domClass.replace('Scene-' + scene + 'OuterBorder', 'taskOuterBorderPressed', 'taskOuterBorder');
            }

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        // This is always called
        _onMouseUp: function(e) {
            var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes['scene'].value;
            if (e.button == 0) {
                console.log('mouse left released, scene=' + scene + ' button=' + e.button);
            } else if(e.button == 2) {
                console.log('mouse right released, scene=' + scene + ' button=' + e.button);
            }
            domClass.replace('Scene-' + this.scene + 'OuterBorder', 'taskOuterBorder', 'taskOuterBorderPressed');
            Tooltip.hide(e.currentTarget);
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        _onMouseEnter: function(e) {
            var label = 'Scene: ' + this.scene + '<BR>State: ' + this.state + '<BR>Target: ' + this.target;
            Tooltip.show(label, e.currentTarget);
            popup.close();
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        _onMouseLeave: function(e) {
            this._onMouseUp('');
            this.inherited(arguments);
            Tooltip.hide(e.currentTarget);
        },

        // This is what is not always called
        _onClick: function(e) {
            var scene = e.currentTarget.attributes['scene'].value;
            console.log('scene ' + scene + ' clicked');
            this._publishEvent(this.scene, 'clicked');
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        _onBlur: function(e) {
            popup.close();
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        //
        _onContextMenu: function(e) {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this._publishEvent({
                'scene': this.scene,
                'sceneId': this.sceneId
            }, 'clicked');
            Tooltip.hide(e.currentTarget);
            var widget = this;
            theNode = 'TaskButtonContainer' + widget.scene;
            console.log('mouse right clicked, scene=' + widget.scene + ' target: ' + e.target + 'current target');

            theTask = missionCache.query({
                'sceneId': this.scene
            }).then(function(results) {
                theTask = results;
                if (widget.state === 'Unassigned' || widget.state === 'Ready') {
                    //The context menu should fire to allow assignment

                    var cb = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
                        style: 'width:96%;background-color:#414141;margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:4px;',
                        name: 'usersByTask',
                        placeholder: 'Assign this task to: ',
                        store: usersContextMenuCB,

                        labelAttr: 'name',
                        searchAttr: 'name',

                        onChange: function() {
                            theTask[0].taskStatus = 'Assigned';
                            theTask[0].taskOwner = this.item.userName;
                            missionCache.put(theTask[0]);
                            console.log('nothing');
                            widget.set('state', 'Assigned');
                            //assignTask(this.item.userName);
                            widget.domNode.classList.remove('Unassigned');
                            widget.domNode.classList.add('Assigned');
                            widget.domNode.setAttribute('dndtype', 'Assigned');
                            this.destroy();

                        },
                        onClose: function() {
                            this.destroy();
                        }
                    });
                    cb.toggleDropDown();
                    popup.open({
                        parent: widget,
                        popup: cb,
                        around: e.target,
                        onClose: function() {
                            popup.close(cb);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },


        _publishEvent: function(sceneNumber, eventName) {
            console.log('publishing ' + eventName + ' for scene ' + sceneNumber);
            topic.publish('TaskButton/tasks', {
                scene: sceneNumber,
                task: this,
                event: eventName
            });
        },

        _setStateAttr: function(newState) {
            if (newState != '') {
                console.log('setting state for scene:' + this.scene + ' to ' + newState);
                this._set('state', newState);
                if (this.innerNode !== undefined) {
                    domClass.replace(this.innerFill, 'task' + newState + 'Background', 'task' + this.previousState + 'Background');
                }
                this.previousState = this.state;
                this.state = newState;
            }
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        _changeTaskState: function(newState) {

            var node = registry.byId(clickedItem);
            if (node !== undefined) {
                node.set('state', newState);
                console.log('changed task ' + this.clickedItem + ' state to ' + newState);
            }

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        _menuTaskDetails: function(e) {
            console.log('do task deatils');
        }

    });
})
```